# jQuery Mobile Responsive Video With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have implemented responsive video using javascript. It is working fine but jquery mobile `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js` 
is removing the right margin and/or makes it impossible to center the video.

[image]

If the above jQuery Mobile code is removed, it works fine.

I need it to be centered with no additional  tags around the video url as the code is an output from a php script.

Html video code:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MItGoIxoVGk" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></strong></p>
```

Responsive Video Javascript Code:

```
// Find all YouTube & Vimeo videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

// The element that is fluid width
$fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

$(this)
.data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

// and remove the hard coded width/height
.removeAttr('height')
.removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

// Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
$allVideos.each(function() {

var $el = $(this);
$el
.width(newWidth)
.height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

});

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

jsfiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/flymen777/hobzq6fu/

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question, don't just link to a fiddle. The fact that you had to "code-block" the fiddle link to get around the validation should've given you that hint already.

Comment: replace `$fluidEl = $("body");` with `$fluidEl = $(".ui-content");`. You need _width_ of content div not body. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hobzq6fu/3/